# how to autocomplete a piece of text around existing text

Tags: vim

I have some code on a server.

I need to keep repeating the same edit around pieces of existing code.

E.g existing code:

`int hello = 1;`

I need to edit this

```
#ifndef X 
int hello = 1;
#else
#endif
```

Is there a way to be able to create a wrapper to autocomplete?

```
#ifndef X
{existing code}
#else
#endif
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the same complex edition to do, I would make a macro (`:help q`) for it.

Answer (score 2):

Use vim [Ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips) with VISUAL selection option:

```
snippet wrap "inserts text around visual selection" w
#ifndef X
${0:${VISUAL}}
#else
#endif
endsnippet
```

After installing Ultisnips set a mapping to edit the snippets:

```
map <Leader>u :UltiSnipsEdit<cr>
```

Now you can copy the snippet seen above and change it accordingly your needs.
The UltiSnips default trigger is <kbd>Tab</kbd> but you can change it easily:

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
```

### How to use it?

Select the line you want to "wrap" with other text, press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then type `wrap` and finally <kbd>Tab</kbd>. NOTE: I am using the word wrap because my choice during the snippet creation, but you can also change it.